# Pick random and remove from collection using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, collections, underscore.js

I've got a collection of **20 results (objects)**, and what I'd like to do when a button is clicked is to:

a) Pick a random object from this collection/array

b) When the button is pressed again - I don't want that object re-picked until the collection is exhausted (i.e. until the 20 items are shown)

I thought of just splicing out the index of that collection, but I'm hoping for a cleaner way using Underscore.js

EXAMPLE:

`var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11...]`

`var getRand = _.random(0, data.length);`

==> 3

Next time I press the button, I don't want the result **"3"** to re-appear as it's been used

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

// cache indexes
var cache = _.map(new Array(data.length + 1).join(), function (item, index) {
  return index;
});

// get random from cached array
var rand = _.random(0, cache.length);

// remove random index from cache
cache.splice(rand, 1);

console.log(rand, cache)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
var picked = [];

$("#link").click(function() {
   if(data.length == 0) return;
   var pick = data.splice(_.random(0,data.length),1);
   picked.push(pick);
   $("#pick").html(pick);
   $("#data").html(data.join(","));
   $("#picked").html(picked.join(","));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3vjk/

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array to store the values you've used and check all new random numbers to see if they appear. This would get messy near the end of the array though as the random number generator tries to guess a single number.

If it were me I would just what you alluded to and take the elements out as you use them and place them into a temporary array. Once all elements are used, reassign the temp array to the original variable name.

Comment: Mention Tags of you question it is useful to get more answers.